# How to only allow certain characters in Tkinter Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner and started using Tkinter. I have 2 entries. For one I only want to allow a 3digit number, no spaces or anything. The other is only allow numbers and letters but limit it to 7 characters again no spaces. How could I do this. Thanks. I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the documentation describing one possible solution.](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html)  Read it, try writing some code, and if it doesn't work, come back with the code and the errors/problems and we can help you.